# make php automatically detect current directory

Tags: php, nginx, directory

On localhost I normally do this

```
file_put_contents('/script.zip', file_get_contents('http://example.com/script.zip'));
```

But it seems on my vps the php file doesn't get doesn't 'detect' the current
directory. So I have to get document_root and manually set the path.

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
file_put_contents($root.'/script.zip', file_get_contents('http://example.com/thescript.zip'));
```

I'm sure there must be a way to configure nginx or php to automatically
detect the current dir, but I can't seem to find how to do that. Maybe
I don't know how to search this specific issue.

Comment: The "current directory" is the directory containing the script, not the document root.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file to be created in you current dir use the '.' as follows :

```
file_put_contents('./script.zip', file_get_contents('http://example.com/script.zip'));
```

The '.' will point to the current directory running the php script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was looking for a solution that would change nginx configuration or a php.ini configuration. In shared hostings I didn't have
to specify document_root either.